# Add image to blank page layout that will be an active hyperlink and have text to the right of it.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, page-layout

I need to create something like this and can't seem to do it. It's driving me crazy.

[image]

I've got a blank page layout and all I want to do is add an image (that when clicked on works as a hyperlink) and have text on the right similar to what is in the photo.

I've tried adding an image but there is no way to add the text or hyperlink.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a page layout then you need to put your image inside  tags or have an onclick to establish a hyperlink on it.  If you want text next to it then you need to use HTML and CSS to achieve the layout.  Something like:

```
<table><tr>
 <td>
  <a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com">
   <img src="<URL of photo>" title="My Photo" />
  </a>
 </td>
 <td>
  This is the text to the right of the photo
 </td>
</tr></table>
```

You will probably want to do this with 's and CSS but the concept is there.

However, if you are talking about editing the content of a page then the principle is the same but easy to achieve.  Assuming you are working in a Page Content area then you can insert a table then add your photo in the left column and your text in the right column.  When you have added your photo then you can select it and click Insert->Link where you add your URL.