# can you create a hyperlinked photo in a sharepoint wiki page?

Tags: 2013, office-365, wiki, hyperlink, wiki-pages

can you create a hyperlinked photo in a sharepoint wiki page?  We are currnetly running 2013 in 365

Comment: Should be the same concept described here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89560/add-image-to-blank-page-layout-that-will-be-an-active-hyperlink-and-have-text-to/89566#89566

Comment: @DavePaylor you should add the comment as answer :)

Comment: The system automatically converts it to a comment as it considers it to be a "trival" answer . . .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a link to a photo.

Check the answer to this question: [Add image to blank page layout that will be an active hyperlink and have text to the right of it.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89560/add-image-to-blank-page-layout-that-will-be-an-active-hyperlink-and-have-text-to/89566#89566)

It should be the same for you.